# How to get non-escaped apostrophe from .components(separatedBy: CharacterSet)

Tags: swift

How I can get `components(separatedBy: CharacterSet)` to return the substrings so that they do not contain escaped apostrophes or single quotes?

<strike>When I print the resulting array, I want it to not include the backslash character.</strike>

I am using a playground to manipulate text and produce output in the terminal that I can copy and use outside of Xcode, so I want to strip the escape character from the string representation produced in the terminal output.

```
var str = "can't,,, won't, ,    good-bye, Santa Claus"

var delimiters = CharacterSet.letters.inverted.subtracting(.whitespaces)
delimiters = delimiters.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-"))
delimiters = delimiters.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "'"))

var result = str.components(separatedBy: delimiters)
    .map({ $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) })
    .filter({ !$0.isEmpty })

print(result) // ["can\'t", "won\'t", "good-bye", "Santa Claus"]
```

Comment: There is no backslashes in your strings. try `result.forEach { print($0) }`

Comment: And to illustrate the problem, `print(["can't", "won't"])` will print with backslashes as well.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Except that it's not a "problem". It just is what it is.

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus, that's basically what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is a metaphysical impossibility. You cannot *want* anything about how `print` prints. It's only a *representation* in the log.

Your strings do not actually *contain* any backslashes, so what's the problem? How the `print` command output *notates* them is irrelevant. You might as well "want" the `print` command to translate your strings into French. No, that's not what it does. It just prints, and the way it prints is the way it prints.

Another way to look at it: An array doesn't contain square brackets at both ends. And a string doesn't contain double-quotes at both ends. Those are things you might write in order express those things as literals, but they are not real as part of the actual object. Well, I don't see you objecting to those!

Basically, if you want to control the output of something, *you* write an output routine. If you're doing to rely on `print`, just accept the funny old way it writes stuff and move on.